# Developing Amazon MWS app with free account?

Tags: amazon-mws

I'm going to develop MWS app for a customer and the problem is that the account that I need seems to be paid.

I simply need to create seller account and my customer to add permissions to me.
However, so far I can't find a way to do this with a free account. The MWS login says that my account is an individual and it's not working and I need to upgrade.

I found this really stupid and I hope I missed something.

Can anybody help with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that there is no way to have free account and to have MWS login.
However, Amazon support give us explanation how the client to get his own keys/secrets which I can use for their MWS API.

Another hint I want to place here is that Products API is NOT for getting your personal products, it's only to search the entire site.
Then Reports API can do the job. Good luck. :)

Answer (score 0):

Contact Amazon Seller Central support and request a sandbox MWS account. The request takes 24-48 hours to complete but it is free and will give you access to post products to all of the ungated Amazon BrowseNodes.

[Seller Support Page](https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/mws/contactus.html)

You'll need to sign up for an account that has access to Seller Central Support. (I signed up for Amazon Payments).

Once your Sandbox account is created. You can give our keys to your client to allow your application access to their account.

Answer (score 0):

You can contact Amazon Support team They will provide you a staging account ,with which you can publish products using MWS service in ungated categories.you don't need to take a seller account at time of development of application.